# Cannot use $_COOKIE to read cookies in Firefox but can see their values when inspecting

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

As the title says, I see the value of cookies set in Firefox but no matter what I do, I cannot read them. What am I doing wrong?

I tried using `$_COOKIE`

I'm simply doing this and getting nothing to print:

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

I expect `print_r($_COOKIE);` to print out all cookies set in Firefox. Instead, I get nothing.

The cookies ARE definitely set though because I see them with the inspector. Also note that the code works perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: `print_r($_COOKIE); die;` check it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the cookies you see in the Inspector? Firefox won't send all of them depending on the configuration, specifically [`sameSite` and `httpsOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies). Other restrictions might apply too, depending on domain, path, etc. You can review some of them in the [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#refsect1-function.setcookie-parameters).